# Parshat Shmini Building of the Mishkan "Vayehi" linked to "Vayehi" in Bereshit, is it linked to 7 days of creation?

Tags: number, parashat-bereishit, parashat-shemini, tractate-megillah

Leviticus Chapter 9

> ‏ א  וַיְהִי, בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁמִינִי, קָרָא מֹשֶׁה, לְאַהֲרֹן וּלְבָנָיו--וּלְזִקְנֵי, יִשְׂרָאֵל.    ‏ 
> 1 And it came to pass on the eighth day, that Moses called Aaron and his sons, and the elders of Israel;

Gemara Megila 10B

> ‏  והכתיב (ויקרא ט') ויהי ביום השמיני, ותניא: אותו היום היתה שמחה לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא כיום שנבראו בו שמים וארץ, כתיב הכא ויהי ביום השמיני, וכתיב התם (בראשית א') ויהי (בקר) (מסורת הש"ס: [ויהי ערב ויהי בקר]) יום אחד   ‏ 
> But is it not written, - And it came to pass on the eighth day, and it has been taught, 'On that day there was joy before the Holy One, blessed be He, as on the day when heaven and earth were created. 
> For it is written, And it came to pass [wa-yehi] on the eighth day, and it is written in the other place, And there was [wa-yehi] one day'?

I am wondering if mefarshim pointed that the creation (Bereshit) is 6 days, that ends also by ויהי (ואני ערב טיבי בוקר יום השישי ויכולו השמים והארץ) or 7 if we count shabbat, and here Tora says the 8th, not the first day of building mishkan? I am not knowledgeable in interpretation of number, but after the above cited Gemara the question appears for me. I was told that Maharal attaches particular importance to the number 8, as beyond the nature.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The Gemara’s just pointing out the word ויהי is a לשון צער, yet seemingly these events are times of joy.